# Como interar jquery con angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Uso `ui-router` con Angular y me gustaría integrar los 2 pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo. El problema es que cuando uso una ruta de ui-router deja de funcionar el  código jquery.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con 'deja de funcionar'? ¿Hay algún error en consola? Muestra la porción de código relevante.

Comment: o sea uso la funcion .click(), cuando cambio de ruta, ya no funciona el click.

Comment: La función [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) es nativa, todo elemento tiene esa función por lo que el uso de jQuery para eso es irrelevante. Añade un código en donde se pueda reproducir el problema.

Comment: Y es posible tener un elemento con angular usando ui-router?

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que uses un Boilerplate de angular, por ejemplo 
https://github.com/jbutko/AngularJS-Boilerplate

Lo mas probable es que estés importando mal las librerias.